# Two molecules with different polarizability in a EM field

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, spectroscopy, molecules, dipole-moment

If I have two molecules with different **constants** polarizabilities $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ and I send and EM field first on the molecule no.$1$ and then on the molecule no.$2$ so that the two molecules will have a dipole moment $\vec{p_1}=\alpha_1\vec{E}$ and $\vec{p_2}=\alpha_2\vec{E}$ what differences will there be in the two molecules?

**1)** Will they both oscillate with the same frequency as the EM field?

**2)** What does the difference in polarizability imply? That they will oscillate with the same $\omega$ but the oscillations of the molecule with the larger $\alpha$ will have larger amplitude?

**3)** Can one know by spectroscopy which of the two molecules has greater polarizability? I mean, we send EM field on the molecules and then the molecules begin to oscillate and generate a new EM field, in the domain of the frequencies we see the external EM field at frequency $\omega$ and the EM field produced by the molecules at the same $\omega$ (*if my hypothesis are right*), so is it possible to distinguish, by spectroscopy, two differents polarisability in a case like this one?

Comment: So they are identical but different?

Comment: @JonCuster I've edited the question.